# Android client communicating with database in jboss server

Tags: android, database, jboss

My android client needs to make a connection to the database in the jboss application server. How can I establish the connection so that I can send the information from both the server and the client? I'm new to Android development, so excuse me on my ignorance.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say "sent the information from both the server and the client"? Do you need to be able to update the DB from the Android app as well as from an application deployed in a JBoss?

Comment: Yes,I should be able to update the DB from the Android app.

Comment: In that case the option given by ottel124 may be good for you: expose the logic related to the data base update as a webservice (if you already have the logic in an EJB or POJO it will be straightforward).  Finally you'll only have to implement the webservice client in your android app. Take a look at the solution given by ottel124.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) on your Jboss AS to access (create, read, update, delete) your hosted resources easily from various (mobile) devices.

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is the reference implementation of JAX-RS, which I'd recommend you to use. Here's an example of calling RESTful services from Android: [Calling RESTful services from your Android app](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076).

Another guide to get into REST on Android is a clip from Google IO 2010: [architectural considerations for developing RESTful applications on the Android platform](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html).